# How can i construct a NEST query with optional parameters?

Tags: elasticsearch, nest

I'm using the NEST .NET client (6.3.1), and trying to compose a search query that is based on a number of (optional) parameters.

Here's what i've got so far:

```
var searchResponse = await _client.SearchAsync<Listing>(s => s
                .Query(qq =>
                {
                    var filters = new List<QueryContainer>();

                    if (filter.CategoryType.HasValue)
                    {
                        filters.Add(qq.Term(p => p.CategoryType, filter.CategoryType.Value));
                    }

                    if (filter.StatusType.HasValue)
                    {
                        filters.Add(qq.Term(p => p.StatusType, filter.StatusType.Value));
                    }

                    if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(filter.Suburb))
                    {
                        filters.Add(qq.Term(p => p.Suburb, filter.Suburb));
                    }

                    return ?????; // what do i do her?
                })
            );
```

`filter` is an object with a bunch of nullable properties. So, whatever has a value i want to add as a match query.

So, to achieve that i'm trying to build up a list of `QueryContainer`'s (not sure that's the right way), but struggling to figure out how to return that as a list of AND predicates.

Any ideas?

Thanks

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Ended up doing it by using the object initialisez method, instead of the Fluent DSL"

```
var searchRequest = new SearchRequest<Listing>
{
   Query = queries
}
```

`queries` is a `List<QueryContainer>`, which i just build up, like this:

```
queries.Add(new MatchQuery
{
   Field = "CategoryType",
   Query = filter.CategoryType
}
```

I feel like there's a better way, and i don't like how i have to hardcode the 'Field' to a string... but it works. Hopefully someone shows me a better way!

Comment: Instead of using strings, you can use `Nest.Infer.Field<Listing>(f => f.CatergoryType)`: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/net-api/current/field-inference.html#nest-infer